# React Native - Webview returned status code

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I'm trying to use Google Docs Viewer to display docs on my app, but sometimes Google returns status code '204' (checked it on Postman) and displays empty webview on app.

Is there any way to catch status code, and ask user to refresh page to see content.